# Hamburger menu causing navbar elements to fall outside nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi when I resize the browser window in chrome/safari (not an issue in FF) the navbar transforms into hamburger menu, as I have coded for. But when I return to desktop size, the menu elements have fallen outside the navbar.

[image]

Here is the header section of my code:

```
<!-- ******HEADER****** --> 
    <header id="header" class="header">  
        <div class="container">      
        <a href="http://178.62.123.221/"><img src="assets/images/figures/logo.png"></a> 

            <nav class="main-nav navbar-right" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button><!--//nav-toggle-->
                </div><!--//navbar-header-->
                <div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active nav-item"><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"> Home</i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#who"><i class="fa fa-question"> Who</i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#what"><i class="fa fa-area-chart"> What</i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#where"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"> Where</i></a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="#tickets"><i class="fa fa-ticket"> Tickets</i></a></li>                
                        <!-- <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false" href="#">Info <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">                                
                                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="/SynapseMissionStatement.pdf" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"> Mission Statement</i></a></li>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="/SynapseEmail.pdf" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-ticket"> Press</i></a></li>                                              
                            </ul>  --> 


                    </ul>
                    <!--//nav-->
                </div><!--//navabr-collapse-->
            </nav><!--//main-nav-->                     
        </div><!--//container-->
    </header><!--//header-->
```

And my styles.css can be seen here: http://178.62.123.221/styles.css

Can anyone advise how I may fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just wonder why you don't add brand-name above navbar-header close tag?

Comment: what do you mean by brand name?

Comment: sorry, I slipped my tongue :p I mean "navbar-brand"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding your logo wrapper a proper float, so it doesn't interfere the way your navigation is positioned:

(better add a class to it, but) for now:

```
#header > .container > a{
    float: left;
}
```